# Laravel Authentication on another backend

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have a python backend for my telegram bot and I have a Laravel app as my frontend. I know it is not optimal, I just do this for practice.

Users are kept on python backend, I use Django on this app. My idea was to have a login form on laravel and sending login/password to python backend to actually authenticate and then keep the token in laravel session or something.

As I am not a big authorization expert I don't really know this approach is correct or even would work.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Why are you mixing two backend frameworks that are built using different programming languages?

Comment: @Daan well my bot was already written in python and I don't want to learn full django just for views, as I am already familiar with blade templates. And practice, as I said.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers